# plt.scatter() plots behaving like plt.plot() plots in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to compare the GDP-per-capita of the world's countries' to each countries' COVID-19 death total. Every time I try to turn it into a scatter plot, it displays the same plot as would be displayed using the `plt.plot()` command. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
data = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/john.smith/covid-data.csv')

gdp = data["gdp_per_capita"]
deaths = data["total_deaths"]

plt.scatter(gdp, deaths)
plt.title('GDP-per-Capita Compared to COVID-19 Death Total')
plt.xlabel('GDP-per-Capita')
plt.ylabel('Confirmed Deaths')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

While running this code, the following graph is produced. This is obviously not the scatter plot I'm trying to get, and it's worth noting that the only thing that changes when I use the `plt.scatter()` command is that the points on the plot just get very large.

[image: Graph produced with faulty code]

I ran a test of the whole Matplotlib module entirely on a different file. When I use normal variables without importing from a CSV file, like this:

```
x = [7, 3, 8, 3]
y = [1, 5, 7, 4]
plt.scatter(x, y)
```

Then the code works perfectly fine and produces a scatter plot. I have been digging for hours online to try and find a solution, and have tried to use other methods of importing CSVs or creating scatter plots but nothing is working. Thank you for any tips.

Comment: This looks to me like a scatter plot where the points are overlapping in a way that makes it look like a bar. One way to check would be to set you xlim and ylim to zoom in on one small section and see if you are indeed seeing many points or one bar

Comment: @G.Anderson You were right, thank you! I wasn't wiser to those commands, but I zoomed into (10000, 2000) and it confirmed what you thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is courtesy of [G. Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7835267/g-anderson) in the comments above.

As it turns out I just didn't have experience with the `xlim()` and `ylim()` commands, so the individual points in the scatter plot just overlapped very tightly in vertical lines. The reason this happened is simply because the original view window was too wide for this large of a dataset.

I did some slight additional research to try and put two plots onto a single figure with one being zoomed in, here's the code:

```
figs, axs = plt.subplots(2)
figs.suptitle('GDP-per-Capita Compared to COVID-19 Death Total')
axs[0].scatter(gdp, deaths)
axs[1].scatter(gdp, deaths)
plt.axis([10000, 20000, 10000, 20000])
```

This produced some nice plots I can use:

[image]

I'm going to look into ways to make the two plots much more readable.

Comment: The way this overlaps the points makes it seem like the data is pre-binned. You might also consider other plot types, since a scatter is likely not as informative. A bar, a histogram, or a box-and-whisker or violin plot might give you more information or tell a better story with the data

Comment: @G.Anderson What do you mean by the data is pre-binned? I've only been programming for a few weeks and just started working with data. I'm currently looking at how to implement different types of plots to get a better read. Thank you!

Comment: By that, I mean that your data is distributed along vertical lines in your scatter plot. It's extremely unusual for scatter data to fall into a series of lines like that naturally. There are likely underlying patterns in the data due to how it was collected or reported (this is common for things like GDP that are more often approximated or rounded in some applications). This might make your scatter plot look more like a histogram (x number of countries in the 18000 gdp category, etc). Always worth looking at other plot types to see what makes the most sense

Comment: @G.Anderson Oh, I see what you mean. After looking at my data it is very precise with the numbers, but the reason there are so many points (more than one for each country) is that I have ~340 entries of GDP and death data for each country (one for each day of 2020). I'm going to look more into using the pandas module to try and pick out only the most recent date for each country and plot just those. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Happy to help! This looks to be a great exercise in Exploratory data analysis

Comment: And don;t forget, you can accept your own answer with the green checkmark to mark the question as resolved